# Письмо приходит пустым на почту

Tags: php, javascript, email, vue.js

Письмо приходит пустым. JS:

```
registerCoupon() {
    axios.post('final/php/registerCoupon.php', new FormData(this.$refs.couponForm))
      .then((res) => {
        if ( res != null ) {
          this.couponPrinter = true;
          this.tel = '';
          this.surname = '';
          console.log(res);
          console.log(this.tel);
          console.log(this.surname);
        } else {
          this.couponPrinter = false;
          alert('Возникла ошибка! Попробуйте позже')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $recepient = "почта";
  $sitename = "mh36.ru";
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $tel = $_POST["tel"];
  $date = trim($_POST['none']);
  $message = "Имя Фамилия: $name \nНомер телефона: $tel \nДата купона: $date";
  $pagetitle = "Бронирование купона";
  mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form @submit.prevent="registerCoupon()" method="post" ref="couponForm">
            <input type="text" name="name" pattern='[а-яА-ЯёЁ]{4,64} [а-яА-ЯёЁ]{4,64}' v-model="surname" placeholder="Введите ваше имя и фамилию" required :title='titleGen'>
            <input type="tel" name="tel" v-model="tel" v-mask="'+7 (###) ###-##-##'" placeholder="Введите ваш номер телефона" required title="Используйте только цифры">
            <button  type="submit">Отправить</button>
            <transition name="fade">
              <div class="p-coupon__activate" v-if="couponPrinter">
                <p>Купон активирован! Вам осталось его распечатать и предъявить администратору. В один день вы можете активировать только один купон!</p>
                <button @click="printCoupon(index)">Распечатать</button>
              </div>
            </transition>
          </form>
```

Comment: Удалил ответ. Поскольку не понял сразу вопрос. В отладчике можете посмотреть, что приходит в $_POST? В js можете вынести new FormData(this.$refs.couponForm) в отдельную переменную и посмотреть, что в нее попадает?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Вывел FormData (http://skrinshoter.ru/s/100718/ZwgTSQDX?a). 
$_POST пустой. Сделал вывод ошибок, выводит это: `Notice: Undefined variable: nameCoupon`. Так с двумя переменными.

Comment: "nameCoupon" такого имени нет ни в одном куске кода, приведенных выше.

Comment: Немного поменял php: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/100718/RUzLHALO?a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь нет проблем. Вы используете Vue странным образом. Не нужно использовать FormData. Почему не используется `data`, `v-model`? Vue для этого и нужен, чтобы связывать данные.

```
axios
  .post(url, {tel: this.tel, surname: this.surname})
  .then(response => { /*...*/ })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

- для данных нужна [валидация](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) перед отправкой
- для данных нужна [валидация на сервере](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.examples.validation.php), хотя бы `isset(..)` или `empty(...)`, но лучше еще и "санитизация" перед отправкой

> **это не ответ в классическом понимании**, это попытка обратить внимание на использование технологии в данном контексте. Может позволит подумать, почитать и сделать лучше.

**upd. рассуждения (к комментариям)**

[Обычно в каждом приложении](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) или компоненте Vue используется атрибут  -   `data: { .. }`, который определяет "реактивные" переменные и именно в этом одна из основных выгод от использования подобных фреймворков:

```
 <form @submit.prevent="register">
    <input ... v-model="tel" v-validate="'required'">
    ...
 </form>


 new Vue({
    data: {
      tel: '',
      surname: '',
      // или
      coupon: {
        tel: '',
        surname: '' 
      }
    },
    methods: {
      register(){
        // do: this.surname, this.tel
        axios
         .post(url, {tel: this.tel, surname: this.surname})
         .then(response => { /*...*/ })
         .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    }
 })
```

`v-model` - [позволяет связать](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) `input` с переменной `tel`, то есть при изменении данных пользователем в форме, изменения "мгновенно" отражаются в приложении. Что избавляет разработчика от "навешивания" слушателей и обработки каждого изменения.  `v-model` - это директива, которая говорит Vue - связать значение с переменной указанной в ней.

> **Если же в вашем приложении Vue только для декорации**, и не используется для манипуляции и отправки данных, можно и [FormData(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData) и [jQuery.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) Да, Vue может использоваться только для валидации или для масок и т.д. Просто нужно помнить, что данные в FormData чистые (raw) и значит никак не связаны c Vue. Vue же позволяет не только связать данные формы, но и добавить перехват на submit.

Примеры Vue [форм с валидацией](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/)

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, по какому принципу формируется цепочка `tel: this.tel`? Ключем является значение `name инпута`, а значением - `v-model инпута`?

Comment: Также забыл добавить, что проверку добавил http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110718/5PEOKMYe?a

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать вместо `this.$refs.couponForm` `id` для формы. И в итоге получиться: `new FormData(document.getElementById('form'))`. Решает проблему